# UIButton image doesn't have the right size on simulator

Tags: ios, image, uibutton

I having a problem while setting an image on a UIButton. Check the image below:

[image]

[image]

As you can see on the first image, on the left side is how the image is displayed on Xcode and on the right side how is displayed on the simulator, which is smaller.

The second image is for reference, it shows how is displayed on different screen sizes on Xcode.

Any ideas on what is going on?

I just added a button to the view and this button has constrains on all sides, just in case anyone is wondering.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch but it may be something to do with retina and non-retina image sizes. Try this.

- Create img1.png of size 100 x 100 pixels
- Create another image img1@2x.png with 200 x 200 pixels
- Add them both to your project
- In your button use img1 in storyboard
- See how it displays in your iphone 5 and iphone 6 simulators.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. I also think that it might be related to the retina thing, but it seems like it's not picking up the @3x file. I have the image in the three formats.

Comment: Do you have the launch images for iphone 6 and 6 plus added to your project? That's the only reason I can think of as to why it wouldn't pickup @3x pics

Comment: Yep, that is already configured. But just in case I tried with the 5s simulator and I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @2x after your image name

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I actually have the three formats, normal, 2x.png and 3x.png.